# How many path patterns can be set for a route in Azure Front door?

Tags: azure-front-door

This document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-front-door-service-limits says that you can have a maximum of 25 path patterns to match for a routing rule in Azure Front door.

I tried setting over 30 paths and that worked fine. Did I missunderstand the limitations or is this just an error in the documentation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only clicked update and not save on the front door configuration, you can add as many as you want and click update on the routing rule but when you click save to actually update the front door the following error appears

"Failed to update the Front Door 'XXXX-dev'. Error: The number of path patterns per routing rule exceeds quota of "25". Please contact support to increase quota."